# C# Visual Studio Lists

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using c# Windows.forms.app on Visual Studio 2017

I'm trying to create a programme that will allow me to get users to choose a movie genre then put films on their choice into the genre and save that data as a variable (Lists or array).

The problem i'm facing is that I'm having to define the list/array objects as opposed to the user creating the object.

[image]

How would I go about doing it?

Global  Variable -

```
NumOfGenres = 0;

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Add a new genre
{
     NumOfGenres++;

     string GenreTitle;

     GenreTitle = My_Dialogs.InputBox("Please name the genre");

     textBox1.Text = GenreTitle;

     List<String> Arrays = new List<string>();
     Console.WriteLine("Enter");
     Arrays.Add(GenreTitle);
}
```

Comment: "Global variable" - there's no such thing as a global variable in c#. That's a field.

Comment: What is the question? You don't know how to get the data? Also: Do define the List<string> outside of the button code and only add the new strings. Also: give your buttons etc better names!!

Comment: listbox 1 and 2 both have lists built in.. if you move one from the other you delete an item from 1 and add it to 2 for example.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the button, you are creating a new list and add the element on it. The logic is ok, but the scope of the list is inside that click button event. The `GC` (Garbage Collector) elimnate it after the end of the event.

Try to declare it on the form scope.

```
List<String> Arrays = new List<string>();

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Add a new genre
{
     NumOfGenres++;

     string GenreTitle = My_Dialogs.InputBox("Please name the genre");

     textBox1.Text = GenreTitle;

     Console.WriteLine("Enter");
     Arrays.Add(GenreTitle);
}
```